# склеить списки по индексу

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
lst = [['D  004660M2   ', 'клей 2-ком', 'KOM', '2.00', 'PDV20', '1135.00', '2270.00', 'BC', '30.00', '53791', '532', 'DE', 'Alles', 'VW', 'AG', '1', '303', 'VW', 'AG', '3506100098', '\n'],
    ['D  004660M2   ', 'клей 2-ком', 'KOM', '10.00', 'PDV20', '1135.00', '11350.00', 'BC', '30.00', '53916', '499', 'DE', 'Alles', 'VW', 'AG', '1', '303', 'VW', 'AG', '3506100098', '\n'],
    ['D  004660M2   ', 'клей 2-ком', 'KOM', '4.00', 'PDV20', '1135.00', '4540.00', 'BC', '30.00', '53791', '532', 'DE', 'Alles', 'VW', 'AG', '1', '303', 'VW', 'AG', '3506100098', '\n'], 
    ['D  004660M2   ', 'клей 2-ком', 'KOM', '10.00', 'PDV20', '1135.00', '11350.00', 'BC', '30.00', '53919', '499', 'DE', 'Alles', 'VW', 'AG', '1', '303', 'VW', 'AG', '3506100098', '\n'],
    ['D  004660M2   ', 'клей 2-ком', 'KOM', '4.00', 'PDV20', '1135.00', '4540.00', 'BC', '30.00', '53796', '532', 'DE', 'Alles', 'VW', 'AG', '1', '303', 'VW', 'AG', '3506100098', '\n']]
```

Есть такой список списков, мне нужно склеить их по признаку 9го индекса если они совпадают значит нужно сложить 3й, 6й и 7й индекс все остальные элементы списка вернуть как есть, уже кучу раз переписывал но так и не получилось склеить...

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, ожидаемый результат

Comment: А что на выходе должно быть? И 7-й индекс текстовый.

Comment: магия какая-то только написал тут... сразу решил =0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По ходу действа заносить элементы списка в словарь по ключу равному элементу с индексом 9. И каждый раз проверять, если такой индекс в словаре уже есть, то сложить нужные поля из словаря и списка, и обновить эти данные в словаре. если такого индекса в словаре ещё нет, то добавить. В конце просто взять все значения из словаря.

```
d = {}
for el in lst:
    if el[9] in d:
        for i in (3,6):
            d[el[9]][i] = str(float(d[el[9]][i]) + float(el[i]))
    else:
        d[el[9]] = el

res = list(d.values())
```

Comment: Чего делать с 7-ым элементом я не понял, т.к. в том элементе содержится тескт.

Comment: перепишу свой код на ваш, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

У меня схожий вариант с *GrAnd*, но несколько в другом ключе. Создаем словарь с ключами по 9-му индексу с нулевым значением, и к нему плюсуем нужные ячейки в цикле. В итоге имеем словарь с ключем по индексу 9 и суммарным значением по ячейкам. Дальше выдаем пару ключ-значение через `items()`.

В переменной `idxs` храним индексы суммируемых столбцов. Могу предположить, что суммировать надо столбцы не `3, 6, 7`, а `3, 5, 6`

```
lst = [['D  004660M2   ', 'клей 2-ком', 'KOM', '2.00', 'PDV20', '1135.00', '2270.00', 'BC', '30.00', '53791', '532', 'DE', 'Alles', 'VW', 'AG', '1', '303', 'VW', 'AG', '3506100098', '\n'],
['D  004660M2   ', 'клей 2-ком', 'KOM', '10.00', 'PDV20', '1135.00', '11350.00', 'BC', '30.00', '53916', '499', 'DE', 'Alles', 'VW', 'AG', '1', '303', 'VW', 'AG', '3506100098', '\n'],
['D  004660M2   ', 'клей 2-ком', 'KOM', '4.00', 'PDV20', '1135.00', '4540.00', 'BC', '30.00', '53791', '532', 'DE', 'Alles', 'VW', 'AG', '1', '303', 'VW', 'AG', '3506100098', '\n'],
['D  004660M2   ', 'клей 2-ком', 'KOM', '10.00', 'PDV20', '1135.00', '11350.00', 'BC', '30.00', '53919', '499', 'DE', 'Alles', 'VW', 'AG', '1', '303', 'VW', 'AG', '3506100098', '\n'],
['D  004660M2   ', 'клей 2-ком', 'KOM', '4.00', 'PDV20', '1135.00', '4540.00', 'BC', '30.00', '53796', '532', 'DE', 'Alles', 'VW', 'AG', '1', '303', 'VW', 'AG', '3506100098', '\n']]

idxs = (3, 5, 6)
comb = dict().fromkeys([v[9] for v in lst], list())
for item in lst:
    comb[item[9]] = [(float(v) + comb[item[9]][iv] if comb.get(item[9])
                      else float(v)) if iv in idxs else v for iv, v in enumerate(item)]

print(*comb.values(), sep='\n')
```

Вывод:

```
['D  004660M2   ', 'клей 2-ком', 'KOM', 6.0, 'PDV20', 2270.0, 6810.0, 'BC', '30.00', '53791', '532', 'DE', 'Alles', 'VW', 'AG', '1', '303', 'VW', 'AG', '3506100098', '\n']
['D  004660M2   ', 'клей 2-ком', 'KOM', 10.0, 'PDV20', 1135.0, 11350.0, 'BC', '30.00', '53916', '499', 'DE', 'Alles', 'VW', 'AG', '1', '303', 'VW', 'AG', '3506100098', '\n']
['D  004660M2   ', 'клей 2-ком', 'KOM', 10.0, 'PDV20', 1135.0, 11350.0, 'BC', '30.00', '53919', '499', 'DE', 'Alles', 'VW', 'AG', '1', '303', 'VW', 'AG', '3506100098', '\n']
['D  004660M2   ', 'клей 2-ком', 'KOM', 4.0, 'PDV20', 1135.0, 4540.0, 'BC', '30.00', '53796', '532', 'DE', 'Alles', 'VW', 'AG', '1', '303', 'VW', 'AG', '3506100098', '\n']
```

Comment: спасибо, не то что у меня 50 строк кода =0

Comment: Ха, посмотрел решение `GrAnd`. Не так понял условие по суммированию))) Сейчас переделаю

Comment: так мне нужен такой-же список на выходе получить. не кортеж, но все ровно мое решение могло бы быть лучше =(

Comment: Вам лучше было бы закинуть тот текстовик, из которого Вы получили этот набор в что-то типа Pandas через `read_csv`. Там бы просуммировали все. Было бы в одну строку.

Comment: Обновил. Правда получилось длиннее немного.

Comment: у меня на выходе получается  59 штук, так как группировка только по 9 индексу, нужно ещё и по 0 =(

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
df[[3,5,6]] = df[[3,5,6]].astype("float")
df[[3,5,6]] = df.groupby(9)[[3,5,6]].transform('sum')
res = df.values.tolist()
```

res:

```
[['D  004660M2   ', 'клей 2-ком', 'KOM', 6.0, 'PDV20', 2270.0, 6810.0, 'BC', '30.00', '53791', '532', 'DE', 'Alles', 'VW', 'AG', '1', '303', 'VW', 'AG', '3506100098', '\n'],
 ['D  004660M2   ', 'клей 2-ком', 'KOM', 10.0, 'PDV20', 1135.0, 11350.0, 'BC', '30.00', '53916', '499', 'DE', 'Alles', 'VW', 'AG', '1', '303', 'VW', 'AG', '3506100098', '\n'],
 ['D  004660M2   ', 'клей 2-ком', 'KOM', 6.0, 'PDV20', 2270.0, 6810.0, 'BC', '30.00', '53791', '532', 'DE', 'Alles', 'VW', 'AG', '1', '303', 'VW', 'AG', '3506100098', '\n'],
 ['D  004660M2   ', 'клей 2-ком', 'KOM', 10.0, 'PDV20', 1135.0, 11350.0, 'BC', '30.00', '53919', '499', 'DE', 'Alles', 'VW', 'AG', '1', '303', 'VW', 'AG', '3506100098', '\n'],
 ['D  004660M2   ', 'клей 2-ком', 'KOM', 4.0, 'PDV20', 1135.0, 4540.0, 'BC', '30.00', '53796', '532', 'DE', 'Alles', 'VW', 'AG', '1', '303', 'VW', 'AG', '3506100098', '\n']]​
```

или, без дубликатов:

```
res = df.drop_duplicates().values.tolist()
```

res:

```
[['D  004660M2   ', 'клей 2-ком', 'KOM', 6.0, 'PDV20', 2270.0, 6810.0, 'BC', '30.00', '53791', '532', 'DE', 'Alles', 'VW', 'AG', '1', '303', 'VW', 'AG', '3506100098', '\n'],
 ['D  004660M2   ', 'клей 2-ком', 'KOM', 10.0, 'PDV20', 1135.0, 11350.0, 'BC', '30.00', '53916', '499', 'DE', 'Alles', 'VW', 'AG', '1', '303', 'VW', 'AG', '3506100098', '\n'],
 ['D  004660M2   ', 'клей 2-ком', 'KOM', 10.0, 'PDV20', 1135.0, 11350.0, 'BC', '30.00', '53919', '499', 'DE', 'Alles', 'VW', 'AG', '1', '303', 'VW', 'AG', '3506100098', '\n'],
 ['D  004660M2   ', 'клей 2-ком', 'KOM', 4.0, 'PDV20', 1135.0, 4540.0, 'BC', '30.00', '53796', '532', 'DE', 'Alles', 'VW', 'AG', '1', '303', 'VW', 'AG', '3506100098', '\n']]
```

Comment: Хм... Должно же было получиться 4 строчки.

Comment: у меня он сумму прописыавет во всех строках, которые группируются. вегда можно убрать дубликаты. (обновил ответ)

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста вот на выходе получил
['07K905715G    ', 'котушка за', 'KOM', '3.0', 'PDV20', '3620.0', '5430.0', 'A6', '30.00', '54097', '105', 'HU', 'Alles', 'VW', 'AG', '1', '303', 'VW', 'AG', '8511300098', '\n']
['07K905715G    ', 'котушка за', 'KOM', '3.0', 'PDV20', '3620.0', '5430.0', 'A6', '30.00', '54097', '105', 'RO', 'Alles', 'VW', 'AG', '1', '303', 'VW', 'AG', '8511300098', '\n']
мне нужно что бы они склеились до 9го индекса, а все что после взять с первого списка. можно сделать это с помощью вашего кода?